# Azure mobile apps with database connectivity

Tags: android, azure, database-connection, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Azure mobile apps and in the process of developing my first App with Azure.

I have a client mobile app on an android phone and and sever side application that does nothing at the moment but hosts a db.

The client mobile app directly updates data in the db but I want to process the newly entered data immediately and send the result to the client mobile app.

I dont know how to trigger the processing on the server side when new data is entered into the db and how to send the result back to the client mobile app.

Comment: What type of db are your app connecting to?

Comment: Hi, It's an sql db hosted in Azure. The webapp is also in azure. and the client app is on the user's mobile phone.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what Azure Mobile App backend you are running (node or .Net).  The basic idea is to put your custom code in the read/insert/update/delete calls as necessary.

- [node example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/tables/todoitem.js)

  - context.execute() executes the call to your DB
- [.Net example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/blob/master/backend/node/TodoSample/tables/todoitem.js)

  - InsertAsync() executes the call to your DB